# BeginningEdit called after commit in WPF DataGrid when Enter pressed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, newline, edit, commit

There is an issue with the DataGrid. Sometimes (usually every 3rd/4th... times) committing the value with [enter] key will start editing the next cell, and automatically types a newline char (making the cell 2 lines), replacing the current value. So like [enter] key is added as if user would have typed it.

I debugged, and what happens when Enter is pressed, CellEditEnding() called with Commit, but right after BeginningEdit() is called by "somebody". The callstack for this unnecessary BeginningEdit() is the same as I start to edit the cell manually.
Note again, this only happens sporadically (but reproducible).
Maybe someone has an idea, what should I start to do with this issue?
Important, it only happens, if the WPF control is embedded into a .NET control via ElementHost, and it's used as a COM control (in our case,from a C++ code).
If the WPF control is used directly in a WPF Window, it's fine, no such behavior.

I attach a screen for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, got some hints here: [WPF TextBox not accepting Input when in ElementHost in Window Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835878/wpf-textbox-not-accepting-input-when-in-elementhost-in-window-forms)

The problem seems to be with the integration of the WPF control into .NET Forms.
When enter is pressed the following events are sent:
WM_KEYDOWN + WM_CHAR + WM_KEYUP.

Ignoring the WM_CHAR for Enter seems to solve the double issue, but keep the enter key working.

```
IntPtr ChildHwndSourceHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_CHAR)
    {
            // avoid duplicated enter when parent window is a native window 
            if (wParam.ToInt32() == 13)
                handled = true; //enter is handled by WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_CHAR follows. Removing this WM_CHAR will solve the double enter issue, but keep the enter working
    }
    if (msg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
    {
        handled = true;
        return new IntPtr(DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_HASSETSEL);
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
...

Loaded += delegate
{
    HwndSource s = HwndSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    if (s != null)
        s.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(ChildHwndSourceHook));
};
```