# ElementHost blocks mouse events

Tags: wpf, winforms, mouseover, visual-studio-extensions, elementhost

**NOTE: I AM TRYING TO SOLVE THE MOUSE ISSUE, NOT THE KEYBOARD PROBLEM, WHICH IS ALREADY SOLVED**

So I am creating a Visual Studio 2015 extension, working on the Options pages.

I am using WPF, so I use ElementHost to host a UserControl.  At first it wasn't receiving keyboard events, so I implemented the solution at:

[WPF TextBox not accepting Input when in ElementHost in Window Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835878/wpf-textbox-not-accepting-input-when-in-elementhost-in-window-forms)

A quick run down of the solution:

A) on the UserControl's Loaded event, I do:

```
var s = HwndSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
s?.AddHook(ChildHwndSourceHook);
```

B) In ChildHwndSourceHook(), I do something like:

```
static IntPtr ChildHwndSourceHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
    {
        handled = true;
        return new IntPtr(DLGC_WANTCHARS | DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_HASSETSEL | DLGC_WANTTAB);
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

HOWEVER, now mouse over events seem to be being ignored, as the cursor doesn't change when moving it over textboxes or grid splitters, not even on new Windows I create.  **Very occasionally**, though, the mouse events do work, though, and continue to work until I move to another page or close the dialog.  That's the weirdest part.

I've tried everything and have scoured Google all day, but I am no closer to understanding why clicks work fine, but mouse over events don't seem to be registered.

I did try REMOVING the message handler, then opening a Window, but it seems once the handler is added, removing it won't fix anything.

Does anyone know how I can get mouse over events to work on my controls?  Thanks so much!

Comment: A piece of code that isn't doing what it should would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found success using the method the creator Viasfora used. You can see the code on the [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora/tree/master/Viasfora/Options). In particular, look at the TextObfuscationDialog and how it is hosted. I believe there might be something wrong with the VS extension documentation, because I ran into the same problem you did.

EDIT:

I've created a sample project to show this method does work (I'm using it in 2 of my own extensions right now). Hopefully this working code might make it easier for you to implement it in your own project.

You can download the source code from my [OneDrive here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6E4F49EE027B8F4C!11960&authkey=!AKpAlPv7u4MrIqE&ithint=file%2Czip).

[image: WPF Options Page]

The `UIElementDialogPage` [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh280174%28v=VS.140,d=hv.2%29.aspx) says:

> Provides seamless hosting of Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   content inside a native dialog running an IsDialogMessage-style
>   message loop. This class enables tabbing into and out of the WPF child
>   window handle (HWND), and enables keyboard navigation within the WPF
>   child HWND.

So while an `ElementHost` will not function correctly within the message loop of a normal/WinForms `DialogPage`, the `UIElementDialogPage` will. There are a number of classes that have `UIElement*` or similar prefix - they are to help migrate the legacy code of VS from Windows Forms to WPF.

Comment: Sorry, your answer actually doesn't work at all.  I looked closer at this code and you are doing little more than wrap the original answer I had implemented into a derived ElementHost class.  It doesn't help with the mouse not changing issue.  :(

Comment: I'll see if I can make a new project with working code that you can use.

Comment: @ChrisBordeman I've edited my answer with a working project. You should be able to take the files directly to your project and refactor them to fit your namespace. I've also added a screenshot to show the proper mouse behavior resulting from this wrapper.

Comment: Ok, your sample works, so you get credit, thanks.  However, all you're doing is deriving TextObfuscationDialog from `UIElementDialogPage` instead of the usual class.  That's it.  I really wish you hadn't wasted hours of my time pointing me to Github, where you did something completely different, reimplementing `UIElementDialogPage` entirely.  That said, I tried deriving from the Shell UIElementDialogPage myself and didn't get it right because I think the Winforms generated code must have not used the new derivation.  I used a plain source file, will let you know if it still doesn't work.  Thx!

Comment: I'm flabbergasted.  It still doesn't work.  I derive from UserControl, and on the Options page I derive from `UIElementDialogPage`.  It's very simple, yet the cursor doesn't change when I mouse over a TextBox. ;(

Comment: Chris, my code is the exact code from the Github link. Sorry you had to spend a lot of time there. I just stripped out all the unnecessary bits. If you post your code, I'd be happy to take a look at it. Btw, I'm assuming the WinForms usercontrol is no longer in the picture, correct? UIElementDialogPage won't host a WinForms control properly, if I read the docs right.

Comment: The Github link had used a reimplementation of `UIElementElementDialogPage`.  Anyway, I figured out my own custom textbox style was causing part of the issue.  Simply using `UIElementElementDialogPage` as my base class solves all issues.  Thanks again.