# WPF Popup and WindowsFormsHost Problem (unresponsive or doesn't close on click outside popup)

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, windowsformshost, windowsformsintegration

my issue is basically a duplicate of unresolved [WPF Popup and WindowsFormsHost Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185985/wpf-popup-and-windowsformshost-problem) , but I was hoping after 10+ years somebody might know an answer.

I'm adding a WindowsFormsHost inside a popup.

```
var host = new WindowsFormsHost();
System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox mtbDate = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox("00/00/0000");
host.Child = mtbDate;
colorPopup.Child = host;
```

and the popup is in xaml

```
<Popup x:Name="colorPopup" StaysOpen="True">
    <TextBox Margin="0,95,365,140"></TextBox>
</Popup>
```

If I set StaysOpen to False, I can interact with other elements in the popup but NOT with the hosted element. Popup closes when i click outside it.

If I set StaysOpen to True, I can interact with the hosted element but the popup doesn't close when clicked outisde the popup.

Any ideas, wallhacks or other gimmicks? I'm pretty desperate.

Note: interaction with the element is not an issue if it's outisde of the popup or if I use new Window instead of popup, but using the popup would be ideal.

Comment: *"after 10+ years"* - now it's less likely someone use winforms in wpf (this is your real problem). The proper solution would be to use just one. You didn't explain why you can't.

Comment: @Sinatr I agree, we are currently moving from winforms to wpf in company and need to be using some hosted elements for the time being. These components are quite complex and customized so there doesn't exist wpf alternative and developing them would take too long currently, it's definitely something we are going to do in the future tho.

Comment: Set StaysOpen to True then in PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event set it to false.

Comment: @MitraM Thanks for the try, I tried to hook the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event to the popup but it never gets fired when clicking on the hosted element.